# Need my table to create only one row per id

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join two tables, which are:

**TABLE 1**

```
t1_id | t1_text | t1_date
```

**TABLE 2**

```
t2_id | t2_text | t2_date | t1_id
```

What i want to get:

```
t1_text | t1_date | t2_text | t2_date
```

table has to show most recent, unique, t1 rows, together with their linked t2_text and its t2_date

This is what ive got so far:

```
SELECT `table_1`.`t1_text` AS 'Text', `table_1`.`t1_date` AS 't1_date', `table_2`.`t2_text` AS 't2_Text', `table_2`.`t2_date` AS 'Date' 
FROM `table_1` 
LEFT JOIN `table_2` ON `table_1`.`t1_id`=`table_2`.`t1_id` 
ORDER BY `table_1`.`t1_date` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Its close, but no cigar. I still get the same t1 rows to show up more than once

Comment: If it's a 1 to many relationship then it will show up more than once. Some sample data and desired output can help.

Comment: can 1 record in t1 have many records in t2? is t1_id unique?

Comment: t2 is for comments, so many

Comment: so if one record has multiple comments do you want to see only the most recent comment?

Comment: Yes! https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6dc39d5AZmY9Um51TcbRj/0 here's where i am at now

Comment: so try my answer

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6dc39d5AZmY9Um51TcbRj/2  << this is what i've got using your query, I still get multiple rows.

Comment: I don't have access to that link. sorry.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand clearly what is your desired output. Try the following:

```
SELECT news.text AS 'News', news.date AS 'Publish date', 
comments.text AS 'Most Recent Comment', comments.date AS 'Comment Date' 
FROM news
JOIN (
    SELECT text, MAX(newsId) as newsId, date
    FROM comments 
    GROUP BY newsId
)comments ON news.newsId=comments.newsId
WHERE comments.text IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY news.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.comments.text' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Sorry that im bothering you so much, bro. Been sitting on things like this the whole day, can't even think anymore

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: My MYSQL version is 5.7.24

Comment: Easy, had 18 more minutes to submit it, and this was only 1/8th of the whole thing lol. Now wheres that champagne

Answer (score 0):

With clarification regarding the uniqueness of the id fields:

```
select  t1.t1_id, t1.t1_date, t1.t1_text, t2.t2_id, t2.t2_date, t2.t2_text
from table_1 t1
inner join (SELECT  t1_id, max(t1_date) as date from table_1) t1m
   on t1.t1_id = t1m.t1_id and t1.t1_date = t1m.date
inner join table_2 t2
   on t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
inner join (SELECT  t2_id, max(t2_date) as date from table_2) t2m
   on t2.t2_id = t2m.t2_id and t2.t2_date = t2m.date;
```

In this query the inline tables select the ids with the max date, which are then joined to the original table to get the remaining fields.

There still may be duplicate t1_id's however if the combination of t1_id and t1_date is not unique.  But in that case I don't think that duplication should be hidden, but rather adressed.

Original answer:

You need to use an inner join rather than a left join.

```
    SELECT `table_1`.`t1_text` AS 'Text', `table_1`.`t1_date` AS 't1_date', `table_2`.`t2_text` AS 't2_Text', `table_2`.`t2_date` AS 'Date'
    FROM `table_1`
    INNER JOIN `table_2`
    ON `table_1`.`t1_id`=`table_2`.`t1_id`
    ORDER BY `table_1`.`t1_date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Also, some of your quote characters are not consistent, different databases may require different quote characters to delimit names, but the mix might give you problems.

Comment: I get the same result both ways, plus it doesn't solve the issue where I am able to get the same row from t1 printed out

Comment: I've got them changed on stackoverflow, they're consistent in my code, but thanks I'll fix it now

Comment: Ah, I assumed t1_id was a unique key, are neither of the id columns unique?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6dc39d5AZmY9Um51TcbRj/0 GOD BLESS THE INTERNET

here's exactly what i've got now